# Trouble with spaces in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a question. I have

```
    set /p displaytext=Text to be displayed:
    echo "%displaytext%"
    pause
```

and if I input something with spaces it displays what i wrote in quotes. How to get rid of them?. Help! Thanks in advanced. Also if i write something in caps with/without spaces it closes. Basically I want it to display exactly what I type no madder what and without quotes.

Comment: can you post the code that you're trying to use?  Seems like it might be something else that can be causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try like below. Just remove the `"` from `"%displaytext%"`

```
@echo off
    set /p displaytext=Text to be displayed:
    echo %displaytext%
    pause
```

For your reference, see output below for test run

```
D:\>test.bat
Text to be displayed:hi there user3671588
hi there user3671588
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: It didn't work.. That's what i said before. If I do that and type something with spaces it closes. -.-. Anyone help?

Comment: @user3671588, did you tried at all? try the posted code once and see if it works or not. See edited answer.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped by clicking the check button under voting button.

Comment: I did use it, then I saw some other posts with the same problem, tried what they said, which was this, and it didnt work.

Comment: plus it works but what if i wanted to put it in something that i dont need pause for? like instead of pause it goes to a location but doesnt clear the screen

Comment: @user3671588, that's altogether a separate question which as such should be posted as separate thread. The solution I given works per your posted question. If you have a separate doubt then post them separately and don't mix them in single post. Post a separate question with all relevent data and if you want me to take a look then post the new thread URL here as comment.

Comment: @Alex, it's great that you want to help but it's always recommended to post separate question in separate thread to avoid clutter and confusion along the same line gaining higher chance of getting accurate/concise answer.